# How to do a subselect using linq method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

How can i do a subselect linq using method syntax, i had tried to google, but no luck. This is my sql query:

```
select * from dwvtextures where id in (select TextureId from dwvtexturetag where TagId = 2)
```

Comment: What ORM are you using? Whichever it is, instead of trying to use LINQ as if it were SQL, define the proper mappings between Textures and TextureTags (ie add a Tags property to Textures), so you can write `var myTextures=dwvtextures.Where(tx=>tx.Tags.Contains(targetTag);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var idList = dwvtexturetag.Select(x => x.TextureId).Where(x => x.TagId = 2);

var result = dwvtextures.Where(d => idList.Contains(d.Id));
```

With the query syntax:

```
from d in dwvtextures
where (from x in dwvtexturetag
       where x.TagId = 2
       select x.TextureId).Contains(d.Id)
select d;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot selman , i have struggled to get the method syntax of query for long time in google, but you did it,thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

```
var innerQuery = from dt in dwvtexturetag  where dt.TagId = 2 select dt.TagId;
var result = from f in dwvtextures where innerQuery.Contains(f.TagId) select f;
```